# How to set Xamarin Forms Label TextType to HTML?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, label

I am trying to set a Xamarin Forms Label's TextType property to HTML. When I set this property as follows I get an error at runtime that says,

> "Could not resolve type with token 0100011b from typeref (expected class 'Xamarin.Forms.TextType' in assembly ..."

I am also unable to set the TextType to Text. I get the same error. How do I set the Label's TextType to HTML?

Code:

```
var lbl = new Label();
lbl.TextType = TextType.Html;
```

Version Info:
Xamarin Forms 4.3.0

Comment: Have you updated the version of xamarin forms to the latest version ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

**C# :**

```
Label label = new Label{
Text = "This is <strong style=\"color:red\">HTML</strong> text.",
TextType = TextType.Html};
```

**XAML :**

```
<Label Text="This is &lt;strong style=&quot;color:red&quot;&gt;HTML&lt;/strong&gt; text."
   TextType="Html"  />
```

or

```
<Label TextType="Html">
<Label.Text>
    &lt;h1&gt;Hello World!&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;br/&gt;SecondLine
</Label.Text>
```

Comment: hey @RangerRick have you tried this code i think will work for you .

Comment: I did try the above suggestions and they all gave me the same error...